# Longitudinal sequence of observations to predict a single target

Tags: regression, time-series, data-transformation, longitudinal-data-analysis

So we observe a population every month and observe set of features $X_{month}$ number of features monthly $X_{Mar,2018}$, $X_{Apr,2018}$ and we want to predict the end-of year value $y_{2018}$, which becomes available only at the end of the year.

In this particular example we predict crop yield (which is at the end of the season) So we want first start predicting at April and gradually improve every month as the new data arrives.

So on April we have four monthly observations to predict end-of-year value.
On May we have five, on June six, ect. all to **predict the same target**.

What would you apply for this problem? Longitudinal models? Time-series analysis? 
How to keep temporal relation between observation of the same object on consecutive months?

Comment: So you want to predict a value for december 2018, given data from january to april 2018?

Comment: not really, I want to predict the final year outcome (the crop yield) by looking at monthly data. So I want first start predicting at June and gradually improve every month as the new data arrives.

Comment: How much data do you have? Do you have historical data from previous years?

Comment: Yes, since 1986, so each of the years and month (and counties) can be used for training

Comment: Then a time series model is probably your best bet, updating it each month to get a (hopefully) better prediction.

Comment: But is it still the same model on may as it was on april? On April I did not have features from May yet, so they were not included... I have different features ieach month.

Comment: What do you mean new features? New variables? Or just new measurements?

Comment: like a new features, e.g. temperature, and growing degree days for a new month, i'd say it is a new feature....or maybe a new measurment

Comment: If these "features" were all present in the previous months then it is not a feature. So if you already measured temperature, degrees, and so in the previous months, and now you are just getting new measurement of them for the current month, then these are new measurements.

Comment: Each month you would build a new model, updating it with the newest measurements, so this would be a different model yes. But this is what you want, since you will get a better model out, more accurate.